# Is "eval" the only way to use JS "switch" as an expression?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, eval

I found that in JavaScript, switch is always a sentence of instruction and using it as an expression will give an error.
So when I have to assign different values to a variable according to different condition, I have to write like this:

```
switch(true){
    case x<0.1: aVariable = '#f0f0f0';break;
    case x<0.2: aVariable = '#d3eadf';break;
    case x<0.3: aVariable = '#bce1cd';break;
    case x>=0.3: aVariable = '#9cd4b9';break;
}
```

Or I should use 'eval()' like this:

```
aVariable = eval("switch(true){"+
    "case x<0.1:'#f0f0f0';break;"+
    "case x<0.2:'#d3eadf';break;"+
    "case x<0.3:'#bce1cd';break;"+
    "case x>=0.3:'#9cd4b9';break;"+
"}");
```

Is there any other way to use switch as an expression rather than a sentence of instruction so that I can make my code less verbose?

Comment: @Andreas The first snippet is from my working app. The second snippet has been tested in the console of Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: Fu** typo... Never mind^^

Comment: @Andreas Well, so it's my typo that caused you to misjudge the result?

Comment: This is definitely a legitimate question, I'm not sure why it has been downvoted - downvoter care to explain?

Comment: @YanYang No my own mistake/stupidity... :(

Comment: @Andreas You are scaring me... :D

Comment: By "sentence of instruction" I guess you mean "statement"?

Comment: Is there some reason you use `x>=0.3` instead of `default`? By they way, your `eval` (second) option won't work, because the `case` statements don't set/do anything with the value.

Comment: @torazaburo Just for semantization. I thought it was not a default setting when no exact options can apply, but another explicit data range. `eval` works in the console of Chrome Developer Tools. Just copy and paste to have a try.

Comment: @torazaburo Maybe... Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a direct approach with an array and calculate the index when you have values with fixed interval. So according to your values, you need

```
value index comment
----- ----- ------------------------------------------
 0.0     0  take integer of value * 10 
 0.05    0  see above
 0.1     1  see above
 0.15    1  see above
 0.2     2  see above
 0.25    2  see above
 0.3     3  see above
 0.35    3  covert by condition and a fixed value of 3
 0.40    3  see above
```

This answer may not look good for four values, but when it comes to more values with fixed intervals, than it is easier to think about an other structure of decision logic.

```js
function color(x) {
    return ['#f0f0f0', '#d3eadf', '#bce1cd', '#9cd4b9'][x > 0.3 ? 3 : x * 10 | 0];
}
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 0.5; i += 0.05) {
    document.write(i.toFixed(4) + ' ' + color(i) + '<br>');
}
```

Comment: Why `x*10|0` return an integer?

Comment: the `|` a *bitwise or* cast the value to integer.

Comment: This is a rather convoluted way of doing it and it only works for the particular example function in the question (i.e what if x is not linear?). This really shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Comment: @CigaretteSmokingMan, "*what if x is not linear?*" then it is a different question and answer.

Comment: Sure, but the question is about how to do achieve a "switch expression" in JS -- how the cases branch is coincidental.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to use a function and invoke it immediately:

```
var aVariable = (function(){  switch(true){
  case x<0.1: return '#f0f0f0';
  case x<0.2: return '#d3eadf';
  case x<0.3: return '#bce1cd';
  case x>=0.3: return '#9cd4b9';
}})(); // call it immediately
```

You can also do this trick with `if`s since `return` short circuits:

```
var aVariable = (function(){
  if (x < 0.1) return '#f0f0f0';
  if (x < 0.2) return '#d3eadf';
  if (x < 0.3) return '#bce1cd';
  if (x >= 0.3) return '#9cd4b9';
})(); // call it immediately
```

Basically, the trick is that we're wrapping it in a function expression which converts it into an expression, this technique of an immediately invoked function expression is a useful trick in JavaScript.

Comment: Mandatory "don't use eval it's slow, hard to debug and problematic" comment.

Comment: I'm not getting why writing `return` is better than writing `avar=`.

Comment: I'm not sure it's better at all - it's a style reference - OP's question was explicitly how to make it an expression which is what `return` does - whether that's better or not is out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very good use of `switch`. The `switch (true)` trick is generally frowned upon. If you do choose to use it, and you do want it to "return" a value, then yes, you could wrap it in an anonymous function. What a lot of extra machinery! Why not just write

```
x < 0.1 ? '#f0f0f0' :
x < 0.2 ? '#d3eadf' :
x < 0.3 ? '#bce1cd' :
'#9cd4b9'
```

This is not to say there are not valid use-cases for wanting a statement or block to return a value, and there have been animated discussion on the ES Discuss group about this very topic. I'm just saying this is not really one of those cases.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the roundabout methods described in other answers, "switch expression" will be achievable when either of the two JS proposals materialize:

- [pattern matching](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pattern-matching)
- [do-expressions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-do-expressions)